# How to set up visualization of event-style models

Tags: alloy

I'm working through the book and trying examples in Alloy 6. For section 6.2.4 "An Event-Based Variation" I can't really understand the results. Specifically removing NoIntervening fact produces counterexample, but even a reduced scope is hard to follow. While trace style was quite easy to understand with simple time-projected visualization. Here are my version of the example ported to Alloy 6: https://gist.github.com/CheatEx/dc7ee7e8bd0750f350c5a270095c792e

The visualization looks totally different from the book. Neither time nor event projections make sense because diagrams are cluttered with either non-relevant events of non-relevant times.

[image]
[image]

Is there a good way to tune visualizer to show the event-style models? Specifically to show only relevant events in time projection?

**EDIT**
A screen with the accepted answer applied
[image: accepted]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to project on Time, to get a representation by instants. Then, the issue is that you still see all events. To keep only events happening in a given moment, you can change the theme to say that Events shouldn't be visible but that the set `pre` should be visible (meaning events whose firing instant is the current instant).

I should add that this can be made completely clearer using the new features of Alloy 6 (there is no finished, printed book describing it yet but there are lecture notes [here](https://haslab.github.io/formal-software-design/)).

Comment: Works great!
Yeah, i've tried to re-write the first example with variables. But it wasn't that easy, so getting back to it later.